# Focus on an arbitrary row / column in a TStringGrid

Tags: delphi

I run Delphi 7 Enterprise on an XP SP3 machine.

I can set focus on a TEdit by using: `TEdit.SetFocus;`

And I can set focus on a `TStringGrid` by using: `TStringGrid.SetFocus;`

But, this is only part of what I want.

How do I set focus on a certain cell (Column/Row) in a `TStringGrid`?

`TStringGrid.SetFocus(Col,Row)`

Answer (score 2):

You define a `TGridRect` for the cell to focus on (select), alternatively range of cells to focus on (if you have `goRangeSelect = True` in `Options`.

Then you select that `TGridRect`.

Example:

```
procedure TForm30.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 AGridRect: TGridRect;
begin
  AGridRect.Left := 2;
  AGridRect.Top  := 2;
  AGridRect.Right := 2;
  AGridRect.Bottom := 2;
  StringGrid1.Selection := AGridRect;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the grid's [`Col`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.Col) and [`Row`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.Row) properties:

> Specifies the index of the column that contains the selected cell.

> Specifies the index of the row that contains the selected cell.

```pascal
StringGrid1.SetFocus;
StringGrid1.Col := Col;
StringGrid1.Row := Row;
```

Which internally just calls the grid's protected `FocusCell()` method, which you can call directly by using an accessor class:

```pascal
type
  TStringGridAccess = class(TStringGrid)
  end;

StringGrid1.SetFocus;
TStringGridAccess(StringGrid1).FocusCell(Col, Row, True);
```